# Nginx Proxy 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, iis

У меня есть веб сервер на IIS 7.5, который на протяжении многих лет исправно работает, но существует проблема, что данная версия IIS не имеет возможности подключения разных сертификатов на разные домены. Обновлять ОС, чтобы поменять версию IIS нет возможности и желания, поэтому я решил воспользоваться прокси Nginx, который слушает 443 порт и перенаправляет все https запросы на 444, где находится IIS https.

Во время работы nginx я стал получать множественные ошибки в логе: `[error] 8056#15884: *1141 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client ...`, приводящие к тому, что клиент получает **502 Bad Gateway** вместо результата.

Во время тестирования и поиска я обнаружил основную страницу, которая так сказать генерирует эти ошибки. Эта страница состоит из множества картинок, которые загружаются различными GET запросами с PHP скрипта. Всего 137 запросов, 102 из которых изображения. Общий "вес" страницы ~ 1 МБ. Часть из этих картинок возвращаются ошибкой **502 Bad Gateway** (5-30 шт) и в результате посетитель не получит то, чего хотел увидеть. Для наглядности прикрепляю скриншот консоли гугла. Подобная проблема наблюдается на любых браузерах, но на IIS таких проблем нет, и никогда не было, я специально проверял, отключая Nginx и пуская IIS напрямую.
[image: google console]

Скажите пожалуйста, как можно исправить ситуацию?

Привожу ниже полный конфиг Nginx, возможно это поможет.

```
worker_processes auto;

#error_log logs/error.log;
#error_log logs/error.log notice;
#error_log logs/error.log info;

events {
    worker_connections 4096;
}

http {
    keepalive_timeout 90;
    keepalive_requests 90;
    client_max_body_size 64M;
    send_timeout 30;

    reset_timedout_connection on;
    access_log off;
    server_tokens off;

    server {
        #listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name *.domain.eu domain.eu;

        ssl_certificate ../cert/domain.eu/fullchain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key ../cert/domain.eu/private.key;

        location / {
            proxy_ignore_client_abort on;

            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_connect_timeout 900;
            proxy_send_timeout 900;
            proxy_read_timeout 900;

            if ($scheme = https) {
                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:444;
            }
            if ($scheme = http) {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Почему, имея возможность на локальном сервере отдавать статику напрямую из `nginx`, вы абсолютно все запросы отправляете на `IIS`?

Comment: Потому что все правила, настройки и прочее изначально написаны для IIS, а это более 60 сайтов и сервисов. Потребность в nginx возникла, когда понадобилось подключать разные сертификаты на разные домены. потому что версия 7.5 этого делать не умеет.

Comment: 502 - это ошибка бэкенда. Скорее всего iis захлебнулся от количества запросов. Ну и проксировать https на https в локалхосте - это бессмысленная трата ресурсов.

Comment: Почему тогда напрямую IIS работает просто отлично, без каких либо ошибок?

Comment: Не знаком с iis. Без понятие какие у него ограничения существуют.